# How to setup 2 switch with VLAN and 2 IPs for each in different block

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, bridge

Below I have depicted the required network. In this network:

- Lets say GW1 is in IP1 block and GW2 is in IP2 block.
- There are 2 Linux running PCs with 4 NICs.
- 1st Linux PC is connected to 2 GWs with different IP block. 1st Linux PC must have 2 IPs assigned to itself and packets coming from 1st port must be tagged.
- For the 3rd port of the 1st Linux PC, one PC must be connected and it must get IP from GW2 and could ping 1st Linux PCs IP assigned by GW2 and it must not get packets from the network items in IP1 block.
- 4th port of the 1st Linux PC must be connected to 2nd Linux PC. This connection must carry both VLAN tagged packets and with no VLAN tagged packets.
- 2nd Linux PC must have again 2 IPs from IP1 and IP2 block and it must be able to talk 1st Linux PC.
- The 1st port of the 2nd Linux PC is connected to PC 2, this PC 2 must have IP from GW1 and must access to 1st Linux PCs IP assigned from GW1 as well.
- The 2nd port of 2nd Linux PC must behave similar to the 1st port and PC 2 and PC 3 can talk each other and also to 1st Linux PC and 2nd Linux in the same block.
- 3rd port of the 2nd Linux PC must have IP from IP2 block and must be able to talk to PC1.
- The items in IP1 must not be able to talk to the ones in IP2 block.

How can we use bridging and VLAN mechanisms in Linux to setup this network? For each Linux PCs can we setup just only using a single bridge instance?

[image: Setup]

Comment: What did you try? What brand of switch? Configuration snippets?

Comment: There are no switches. Linux PCs will behave like switch, we need to use vconfig, brctl like tools to create such a network.